# Binding Static ICommand Variable grays out button?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

Continuing with my struggle with Static variables and XAML, I can't work around the command bindings greying out the button.

The code in View Model:

```
public static ICommand CancelCalender => _cancelCalender
          ?? (_cancelCalender = new CommandHandler(CancelCalender_Button, _canExecute));


public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    private Action _action;
    private bool _canExecute;
    public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }
}
```

The reference,

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:StaffShiftManager.ViewModels"
```

And these are the ways I tried to bind the command variable:

```
Command="{x:Static viewModels:ViewModelBase.CancelCalender}"
```

And

```
Command="viewModels:ViewModelBase.CancelCalender"
```

And

```
Command="{Binding Source={x:Static viewModels:ViewModelBase.CancelCalender}}"
```

Is there something that I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont ever see how `_canExecute` is ever set to true? Returning `false` from the `CanExecute()` will disable (gray out) the button.

Comment: @Nico, I don't know why I had it like that, I originally set it like this `return true;` in the `_canExecute` method. Anyway, that fixed it. Make it an answer and I will up vote and mark it solved

Comment: Note that you use the old Binding expression syntax again. Better write `Command="{Binding Path=(viewModels:ViewModelBase.CancelCalender)}"` and stick to it for all your static properties. There wouldn't be any need to "try to bind" anymore.

Comment: @Clemens, Thanks again for all the help. Sometimes I wish you could give rep for great comments like theses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically in the ICommand `CanExecute()` method, this returns wether or not the Command is enabled \ can execute.

Returning `false` from the `CanExecute()` will disable (gray out) the button.

Now I have modified your code slightly to provide a `Func<bool>` as the `CanExecute()` handler. What will happen here is every time the Command Execution is re-queried it will execute your `canExecute` method.

```
public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    public CommandHandler(Action execute)
        :this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public CommandHandler(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

        _executeHandler = execute;
        _canExecuteHandler = canExecute ?? (() => true);
    }


    Func<bool> _canExecuteHandler = () => true;
    Action _executeHandler;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecuteHandler();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeHandler?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Not that the default implementation for the `canExecute` method is to return `true`. Even passing a null `Func` to the constructor will still result in true.

Just to add one more thing one of my favorite command binders (much more advanced than above) is using the [`DelegateCommand`](https://gist.github.com/Nico-VanHaaster/cedd82fdb53487fcb930fe2f526960b8). I dont remeber where I found the original source (as I did not write it) but is much more advanced.

Comment: Thanks for the extra bit of advice.  One question, resharper is telling me `_canExecuteHandler` can be made `readonly` , I am gathering that doing that won't affect this in any way? Cheers.

Comment: Yes that is true both the `_executeHandler` and `_canExecuteHandler` can be made `readonly` as they should not change (only assigned in the constructor).

Comment: Ahh, thats why it is suggesting that. another thing learned today. Again, thanks for the help it is really appreciated.